# How can devices exchange data over data link layer 2?

Tags: linux, bash, networking

I have a collection of wifi enabled linux devices.

I would like to configure one to use the wifi and the rest to automatically join the same network. It seems to me if I could set up a data link client/server model, all the devices could exchange network credentials and join the same wifi network. Is this possible? Can it be done over command line? How can devices communicate when they have not yet joined a network or received and ip address?

Comment: "_...if I could set up a data link client/server model..._" Layer-2, the data-link layer, is a peer-to-peer network layer. The client/server model is an application-layer concept. Layers 1 to 4 are all peer-to-peer connections.

Answer (score 0):

For your devices to communicate they need to connect to *something*.  Since your goal is to have them learn WiFi credentials X, we should assume they can't use credentials X to connect to each other.  So they'll have to do something peer-to-peer.  Some ideas:

1. Have the one device which knows credentials X create an "ad hoc" WiFi network.  Have the others join it and connect to the creator to learn credentials X.
2. Use an alternate protocol for credential exchange, such as Bluetooth.

Neither of these  ideas will be best implemented in Bash.  Something like Python or C may be easier.